# Apache URL redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect, mod-alias

I would like to set up an Apache redirect rule which will accept the following browser URL:

```
192.168.100.128/test
```

and transform it into the following:

```
http://192.168.100.128:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=testjpi
```

I have had a look at the httpd.conf and have tried to use both the Alais and Rewrite modules but I can't get either to work.

Alias:

```
Alias /test http://192.168.100.128:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=testjpi
```

And also Rewrite:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteRule    http://192.168.100.128/test  http://192.168.100.128:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=testjpi
 RewriteRule    /test   http://192.168.100.128:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=testjpi 
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas if what I'm doing is even possible, and if so, how do I go about getting it right?  I have limited knowledge of Apache so I'm going in a bit blind.

TIA.

Comment: You added the rules but you have not set any flags for redirection. Add `[R=301,L]` in last rewriterule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias won't work on URLs it only works to directories.

Try:

```
Redirect permanent /test http://192.168.100.128:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=testjpi
```

for more documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect